# Cosa significa "far attrito" in questa frase?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Nel racconto *L'inseguimento* di Italo Calvino ho letto:

> Insomma colui che in questo momento è il mio nemico capitale si trova disperso in
>   mezzo a tanti altri corpi solidi sui quali la mia avversione e paura è obbligata a distribuirsi e a *far attrito*, così come la sua volontà omicida per quanto diretta esclusivamente contro di me si trova come sparpagliata e deviata tra un gran numero di oggetti intermedi.

Ho cercato il termine "attrito" in alcuni dizionari, comunque non riesco a capire il significato dell'espressione "far attrito" nella frase precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Attrito](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/attrito.shtml):

> - fis. forza che contrasta il moto relativo di un corpo rispetto a un altro, per  estensione  *sfregamento*. (Sabatini Coletti)

- ***Fare attrito, ossia sfregare contro***. Nel testo viene usata in senso metaforico per indicare un contatto sgradevole, quello della sua avversione e paura contro i corpi solidi.
- La metafora della paura che non scivola ma è costretta a fare attrito contro i corpi solidi amplifica l'effetto del disagio e dello spavento  che l'autore percepisce.

Comment: So cos'è "sfregare", ma non capisco molto bene il significato di "sfregare contro": fare resistenza?

Comment: No, pensa a quando si passa con la macchina troppo vicino ad un muro, strisciando contro il muro....rende l'idea?

Comment: Capisco, grazie!

Comment: Non conosco questo passo, ma dato che Calvino ne sapeva di argomenti scientifici, aggiungo che probabilmente la metafora si estende al fatto che, così come l'attrito dissipa l'energia cinetica dei corpi che vi partecipano (in genere trasformandola in forme più disordinate di energia), così l'“avversione e paura” del personaggio sembrerebbero dissiparsi, indebolirsi venendo a contatto con troppi altri oggetti oltre al “nemico capitale”.

Comment: Comunque, se l'attrito è quello che in inglese si chiama "friction", si tratta di una forza di resistenza (nel senso che si oppone al movimento del corpo).

Comment: @DaG: Il narratore è in un ingorgo di traffico, i "corpi solidi" sono le altre macchine e "il nemico capitale" è una macchina che lo sta inseguendo, anche questa intrappolata nell'ingorgo, il cui occupante vuole ammazzare il narratore. La tua osservazione è interessante.