# Perché "d'Italo" non è corretto?

Tags: prepositions, orthography, pronunciation

Ho ricevuto una correzione a questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5979/707), accompagnata dal commento «Qui non si può proprio scrivere "d'Italo". È corretto "di Italo"». Cercando informazioni sull'apostrofo con la preposizione "di", ho trovato [questa spiegazione](http://www.mtcube.com/manuali/le-basi/RegoleDimenticate.pdf):

> La preposizione DI si elide di norma nei nomi propri e in determinate espressioni 
>   avverbiali:
>
> > Santa Teresa d’Avila, d’accordo, ecc.
>
> In tutti gli altri casi l’elisione è facoltativa:
>
> > parola d’amico e parola di amico 
> >     ecc.

Non riesco a capire perché scrivere "un romanzo d'Italo Calvino" non è corretto. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Penso che sia tecnicamente corretto, ma suona malissimo.

Comment: È sbagliato perché, in accordo con una ben nota regola dell'italiano, è vietato apostrofare la «d» nel caso dei nomi propri di persona, di talchè non solo *d'Italo* è sbagliato, ma anche *d'Anna*, *d'Elisa*, *d'Oronzo* e *d'Umberto*.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider, confesso che non conosco questa “ben nota regola dell'italiano”: potresti suffragarla con qualche fonte?

Answer (score 3):

Non è un problema di correttezza, riguarda il soggetto o contesto a cui ti stai riferendo, ed è più per un discorso di "scorrevolezza".

Faccio un esempio semplice.

Se in una frase si volesse fare un esempio come sto facendo io, **dicendo "e ad esempio" sarebbe corretto**. Ma se decidessi di scrivere **"ed ad esempio", sarebbe corretto comunque** (http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/A/a-ad.shtml).

La differenza è che, mentre si parla, è normale non essere letterali totalmente, e quindi non scandire le lettere finali. Dovrebbe essere naturale invece, cercare di "addolcire" e rendere più scorrevole il testo o la lingua parlata.

In questo caso, come hai già notato, dire "d'Italo" o dire "di Italo" è indifferente, l'unica differenza a livello, non di correttezza ortografica, ma piuttosto di rispetto verso la persona, è utilizzare un apostrofo o no.

Faccio altri due esempi.

Supponiamo di avere un amico, che si chiama appunto, Italo. Italo ha comprato un'auto che vediamo per strada.

Possiamo dire che "l'auto è d'Italo" (pronunciandolo, suona scorrevole).
Oppure possiamo dire "l'auto è di Italo" (ma sembra che ci stiamo riferendo all'autore delle opere, e non all'amico).

In genere, in ambito formale, si tenta di diminuire il numero di apostrofi, e contrazioni, dando meno "confidenza" all'interlocutore. Sono differenze sottili, che possiamo trovare sempre tra amici.

Utilizzando l'espressione "l'amico mio" si dimostra confidenza con la persona in questione.

Dicendo invece "al mio amico", suona più "*friendly*", meno confidenziale e meno restrittivo.

Tornando al tuo discorso, ti porto un paio di esempi di nomi, con cui si usa "di", sempre di scrittori. (Oltretutto, leggendolo, sembra una forma arcaica, mettere la preposizione con apostrofo a volte.)

Le opere di Omero.

Le poesie di Emily Dickinson.

Dorian Gray di Oscar Wilde.

Ce ne sono molti di esempi. In sostanza, cerca di evitare di usare la forma contratta con nomi propri perché suona male, perché per essere corretto è corretto.

Comment: Non ho capito il discorso del “rispetto della persona” e tutto quello che viene dopo. Potresti sintetizzare e chiarire (magari facendo attenzione a spazi, maiuscole e apostrofi, visto il sito e visto il contesto)?

Comment: Curioso perché la spiegazione citata nella domanda afferma che la preposizione "di" si elide con i nomi propri. Per esempio: "d'Avila".

Answer (score 1):

Ritengo sia un problema di accenti: Italo si pronuncia accentando la i (*ì-talo*) ma d'Italo è difficile da pronunciare *dì-talo*, diventa piuttosto *dita-lo* (o *diita-lo* o peggio *ditta-lo*), perdendo completamente il nesso con l'originale. A questo punto, per conservare il tono della *ì*, meglio raddoppiarla risultando in *diì-talo*.

Comment: Sinceramente non capisco perché chi ha messo il downvoto non spieghi perché, ciò visto che il punto di vista proposto non appare del tutto astruso. Io ora metto un bel upvoto.

Comment: Hai pienamente ragione, @ElberichSchneider. Prima di tutto, la risposta non è ben intelligibile perché non è chiaro cosa intenda con grafie come “*dita-lo*” e le altre. Dov'è l'accento? C'è una pausa in corrispondenza del trattino? Ma soprattutto, non si vede il nesso tra queste nebulose pronunce e la scrittura “d'Italo”. Perché dovrebbe apparire il trattino prima di “lo” (qualunque cosa significhi)? Perché dovrebbe raddoppiare la “i”? Perché dovrebbe raddoppiare la “t”? Tutto il ragionamento pare improntato solo al modo soggettivo in cui lo scrivente percepisce quella stringa di caratteri.

Comment: Non sono molto esperto di trascrizione fonetica. Utilizzando un SW trovato online che dice di riuscire a trascrivere l'italiano posso dare le seguenti trascrizioni IPA: *di iˈtaːlo* è la pronuncia standard, *d iˈtaːlo* la pronuncia, ancora corretta ma un po' retrò, della grafia con l'apostrofo, *'di:ta lo* o *diθaːlo* le pronunce errate che possono derivare dalla soppressione della pausa dopo la preposizione. Nelle varie declinazioni dialettali dell'italiano (come suggerisce @alsa) si preferiscono quelle variazioni che meglio si adeguano alla cadenza locale ma divergono dallo standard.

Answer (score 1):

Al mio paese (provincia di Pisa) l'auto di mio cugino è certamente "la macchina d'Ivano" e non è coinvolta alcuna mancanza di rispetto. Lo stesso per "la casa d'Ivano". E i fiori della vicina di mia nonna, in un paesino un po' più in là, erano "i gerani d'Ivonne". A Genova, si direbbe "di Ivano" e "di Ivonne". A pochi km da casa mia (provincia di Gorizia) c'è "San Pier d'Isonzo", se può essere utile. Gusti son gusti. Non mi risulta che ci siano le regole.